# Is there a way to make terrain generation with JPanels and Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, 2d

I have been wanting to make an array of JPanels(a 3 by 3 array) with a randomly generated JPanel that is either a forest or plains, with the center one always being one called house. There will always be one visible, and I want it so when the x-position of a JLabel called character reaches x-position 0, it will check which JPanel in that array is being used as a ContentPane, and if this event happens in a JPanel that is in the first column, it will do a System.out.Println("Hello!") kind of thing but if this happens in the other two columns, the contentpane will be set to whatever row this happened on-1 column. This is the same with the y-position of this JLabel. Do I need this to be in a thread since it should constantly check if the x or y-position has reached 0? If needed, I could post the code, but I just need an example. The class that has the whole Swing window extends JFrame, if it is necessary and the main class calls the object Window where everything is, such as the window and JLabel.

I expect it to be like Minecraft world generation, but if it was 2D, made in Java Swing, and only one chunk for the sake of detail. I have tried this:

```
        while(true){
            switch(guineaXPosition) {
            case 0:
                for (int i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
                    for(int j=0;i<world.length;j++) {
                      if (frame.getContentPane()==world[i][0]) {
                        // The guinea is in the JPanel at index [i][j].
                        // Perform the desired action.
                          System.out.println("Edge of world, nothing you can do!");
                      }else {
                          frame.setContentPane(world[i][j-1]);
                      }}
                    }               
                    break;
            case 1300:
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

in one thread and did this in another thread:

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int terrainTypeGen=random.nextInt(2)+1;
        for(int i=0;i<world.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<world[0].length;j++) {
                if(i==1&&j==1) {
                    world[i][j]=new JPanel();
                }else {
                    String terrainType=null;
                    if(terrainTypeGen==1) {
                        world[i][j]=new JPanel();
                        world[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }else if(terrainTypeGen==2) {
                        world[i][j]=new JPanel();
                        world[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please don't judge me.
And please tell me if any more detail is required.

Comment: I would probably do something a little different, apart from not using the `JFrame` as your primary surface, I would generate a "world" model, which would maintain information about the type of biome is at what types of areas/chunks.  I would then, when the user moves to this area, look to see if a panel exists for that chunk, if it does, present it, if it doesn't create it.  This way you're loading components you don't need (and caching them as you use them)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you give an example of the type of code I would use?

Answer (score 2):

> Could you give an example of the type of code I would use?

You may regret that.

First, you should start by defining some models which describe your data. This allows you to decouple your UI from your data (this is the bases of the "model-view-controller" concept)...

```
public enum Biome {
    FOREST, PLAINS
}

public interface Chunk {
    public Biome getBiome();
    public Point getLocation();
}

public interface World {
    public Chunk getChunkAt(int x, int y);
}
```

That's pretty basic, but we also need some way to be able to create random chunks, in this case we can use a concept of a factory...

```
public interface ChunkFactory {
    public Chunk createChunk(Point worldLocation);
}
```

> But why are we using `interface`s?

Interfaces allow you to define the contracts of your code without been tied to individual implementations.  This also supports the "dependency injection" principle.

Next, we need to define some kind of model to store our chunks in, one which can by randomly accessed and which can dynamically grow based on the data been placed in it.

To this end, I'd consider some kind of "matrix".  You could use a two dimensional array, but where's the fun in that .

The follow is a concept of a "matrix" backed by `Map`...

```
// This basically acts a multi dimensional matrix of values, keyed by the
// x/y coordinates.
public interface Matrix<Type> {
    public Type get(int x, int y);
    public void put(Type value, int x, int y);
}

public class HashMapMatrix<Type> implements Matrix<Type> {        
    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Type>> values = new HashMap<>(8);
    
    @Override
    public Type get(int x, int y) {
        Map<Integer, Type> rows = values.get(y);
        if (rows == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return rows.get(x);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void put(Type value, int x, int y) {
        Map<Integer, Type> rows = values.get(y);
        if (rows == null) {
            rows = new HashMap<Integer, Type>(8);
            values.put(y, rows);
        }
        rows.put(x, value);
    }
}
```

Now, we can get started with some initial implementations...

```
public class DefaultChunkFactory implements ChunkFactory {
    
    private List<Biome> listOfBiomes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Biome.values()));
    
    protected List<Biome> getListOfBiomes() {
        return listOfBiomes;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Chunk createChunk(Point worldLocation) {
        List<Biome> biomes = new ArrayList<>(getListOfBiomes());
        Collections.shuffle(biomes);
        Biome biome = biomes.get(0);
        return new DefaultChunk(biome, worldLocation);
    }
}

public class DefaultChunk implements Chunk {        
    private Biome biome;
    private Point location;

    public DefaultChunk(Biome biome, Point location) {
        this.biome = biome;
        this.location = new Point(location);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Biome getBiome() {
        return biome;
    }        

    @Override
    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}

public class DefaultWorld implements World {
    
    private Matrix<Chunk> chunkMatrix = new HashMapMatrix<>();
    private ChunkFactory chunkFactory;

    public DefaultWorld(ChunkFactory chunkFactory) {
        this.chunkFactory = chunkFactory;
    }

    public ChunkFactory getChunkFactory() {
        return chunkFactory;
    }
    
    protected Matrix<Chunk> getChunks() {
        return chunkMatrix;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Chunk getChunkAt(int x, int y) {
        Chunk chunk = getChunks().get(x, y);
        if (chunk == null) {
            chunk = getChunkFactory().createChunk(new Point(x, y));
            getChunks().put(chunk, x, y);
        }
        return chunk;
    }
}
```

these are pretty basic, but they build the concept of the "world" and "chunks".

And finally, we can get start with the UI!

First, a component which can represent a `Chunk`

```
public class ChunkPane extends JPanel {
    private Chunk chunk;

    public ChunkPane(Chunk chunk) {
        this.chunk = chunk;
        switch (chunk.getBiome()) {
            case FOREST:
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case PLAINS:
                setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                break;
        }
        
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        Point location = chunk.getLocation();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(location.x + "x" + location.y);
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
}
```

This is pretty basic, it sets it's background color based on the biome and displays the chunk location within the world.

Okay, next, we need a "world" pane which can manage the display of the chunks based on the location of the player.

```
public class SwingCraft extends JPanel {
    protected enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }
    
    private Matrix<ChunkPane> chunkMatrix = new HashMapMatrix<ChunkPane>();
    
    private World world;
    private Point playerLocation = new Point(0, 0);
    
    public SwingCraft(World world) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.world = world;
        setChunk(playerLocation);
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), Direction.LEFT);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), Direction.RIGHT);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), Direction.UP);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), Direction.DOWN);
        
        actionMap.put(Direction.LEFT, new MoveAction(-1, 0));
        actionMap.put(Direction.RIGHT, new MoveAction(1, 0));
        actionMap.put(Direction.UP, new MoveAction(0, -1));
        actionMap.put(Direction.DOWN, new MoveAction(0, 1));
    }
    
    public void setChunk(Point location) {
        ChunkPane pane = chunkMatrix.get(location.x, location.y);
        if (pane == null) {
            Chunk chunk = world.getChunkAt(location.x, location.y);
            pane = new ChunkPane(chunk);
            chunkMatrix.put(pane, location.x, location.y);
        }
        
        removeAll();
        add(pane);
        
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    
    protected void moveBy(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
        int targetX = playerLocation.x + xDelta;
        int targetY = playerLocation.y + yDelta;
        
        playerLocation.x = targetX;
        playerLocation.y = targetY;
        
        setChunk(playerLocation);
    }
    
    protected class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private int xDelta, yDelta;

        public MoveAction(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            this.xDelta = xDelta;
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            moveBy(xDelta, yDelta);
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty basic.  It provides a simple navigation using key bindings which will either display the cached biome pane if available or create new chunk and pane and display that.

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new SwingCraft(new DefaultWorld(new DefaultChunkFactory())));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SwingCraft extends JPanel {
        protected enum Direction {
            UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
        }

        private Matrix<ChunkPane> chunkMatrix = new HashMapMatrix<ChunkPane>();

        private World world;
        private Point playerLocation = new Point(0, 0);

        public SwingCraft(World world) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.world = world;
            setChunk(playerLocation);
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), Direction.LEFT);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), Direction.RIGHT);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), Direction.UP);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), Direction.DOWN);

            actionMap.put(Direction.LEFT, new MoveAction(-1, 0));
            actionMap.put(Direction.RIGHT, new MoveAction(1, 0));
            actionMap.put(Direction.UP, new MoveAction(0, -1));
            actionMap.put(Direction.DOWN, new MoveAction(0, 1));
        }

        public void setChunk(Point location) {
            ChunkPane pane = chunkMatrix.get(location.x, location.y);
            if (pane == null) {
                Chunk chunk = world.getChunkAt(location.x, location.y);
                pane = new ChunkPane(chunk);
                chunkMatrix.put(pane, location.x, location.y);
            }

            removeAll();
            add(pane);

            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        protected void moveBy(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
            int targetX = playerLocation.x + xDelta;
            int targetY = playerLocation.y + yDelta;

            playerLocation.x = targetX;
            playerLocation.y = targetY;

            setChunk(playerLocation);
        }

        protected class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
            private int xDelta, yDelta;

            public MoveAction(int xDelta, int yDelta) {
                this.xDelta = xDelta;
                this.yDelta = yDelta;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                moveBy(xDelta, yDelta);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ChunkPane extends JPanel {
        private Chunk chunk;

        public ChunkPane(Chunk chunk) {
            this.chunk = chunk;
            switch (chunk.getBiome()) {
                case FOREST:
                    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case PLAINS:
                    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
            }

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            Point location = chunk.getLocation();
            JLabel label = new JLabel(location.x + "x" + location.y);
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

    // This basically acts a multi dimensional matrix of values, keyed by the
    // x/y coordinates.
    public interface Matrix<Type> {
        public Type get(int x, int y);
        public void put(Type value, int x, int y);
    }

    public class HashMapMatrix<Type> implements Matrix<Type> {        
        private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Type>> values = new HashMap<>(8);

        @Override
        public Type get(int x, int y) {
            Map<Integer, Type> rows = values.get(y);
            if (rows == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return rows.get(x);
        }

        @Override
        public void put(Type value, int x, int y) {
            Map<Integer, Type> rows = values.get(y);
            if (rows == null) {
                rows = new HashMap<Integer, Type>(8);
                values.put(y, rows);
            }
            rows.put(x, value);
        }
    }

    public enum Biome {
        FOREST, PLAINS
    }

    public interface Chunk {
        public Biome getBiome();
        public Point getLocation();
    }

    public interface World {
        public Chunk getChunkAt(int x, int y);
    }

    public interface ChunkFactory {
        public Chunk createChunk(Point worldLocation);
    }

    public class DefaultChunkFactory implements ChunkFactory {

        private List<Biome> listOfBiomes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Biome.values()));

        protected List<Biome> getListOfBiomes() {
            return listOfBiomes;
        }

        @Override
        public Chunk createChunk(Point worldLocation) {
            List<Biome> biomes = new ArrayList<>(getListOfBiomes());
            Collections.shuffle(biomes);
            Biome biome = biomes.get(0);
            return new DefaultChunk(biome, worldLocation);
        }
    }

    public class DefaultChunk implements Chunk {        
        private Biome biome;
        private Point location;

        public DefaultChunk(Biome biome, Point location) {
            this.biome = biome;
            this.location = new Point(location);
        }

        @Override
        public Biome getBiome() {
            return biome;
        }        

        @Override
        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }
    }

    public class DefaultWorld implements World {

        private Matrix<Chunk> chunkMatrix = new HashMapMatrix<>();
        private ChunkFactory chunkFactory;

        public DefaultWorld(ChunkFactory chunkFactory) {
            this.chunkFactory = chunkFactory;
        }

        public ChunkFactory getChunkFactory() {
            return chunkFactory;
        }

        protected Matrix<Chunk> getChunks() {
            return chunkMatrix;
        }

        @Override
        public Chunk getChunkAt(int x, int y) {
            Chunk chunk = getChunks().get(x, y);
            if (chunk == null) {
                chunk = getChunkFactory().createChunk(new Point(x, y));
                getChunks().put(chunk, x, y);
            }
            return chunk;
        }
    }
}
```